# A script that deletes all tables in Hbase

Tags: command-line, hbase

I can tell hbase to disable and delete particular tables using:

```
disable 'tablename'
drop 'tablename'
```

But I want to delete all the tables in the database without hardcoding the names of any of the tables. Is there a way to do this? I want to do this through the command-line utility `./hbase shell`, not through Java or Thrift.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[disable_all](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/0.94/src/main/ruby/shell/commands/disable_all.rb) and [drop_all](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/0.94/src/main/ruby/shell/commands/drop_all.rb) have been added as commands in the HBase ruby shell.  These commands were added in jira [HBASE-3506](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-3506)  These commands take a regex of tables to disable/drop.  And they will ask for confirmation before continuing.  That should make droping lots of tables pretty easy and not require outside libraries or scripting.

Comment: Note that `disable_all '*.*'` is the appropriate command to disable all HBase tables. When using `disable_all '*'`, you will receive an incorrect disable confirmation from HBase; this is a [known issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-6642) that's fixed in HBase 0.94.4 onwards.

Comment: Thanks Emaad for that tip. I can confirm that it still isn't fixed in 0.94.5.

Comment: If you want to delete all tables in namespace. Run disable_all 'namespace_name:.*' and drop_all 'namespace_name:.*' in hbase shell.

Answer (score 10):

I have a handy script that does exactly this, using the Python [Happybase](https://github.com/wbolster/happybase/) library:

```py
import happybase

c = happybase.Connection()

for table in c.tables():
  c.disable_table(table)
  c.delete_table(table)
  print "Deleted: " + table
```

You will need Happybase installed to use this script, and you can install it as:

```
sudo easy_install happybase
```

Comment: happybase is really cool.. infact I am using it for monitoring hbase purposes as well..

Comment: This can also be done in one go: connection.delete_table('table-name', disable=True) http://happybase.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#happybase.Connection.delete_table

Answer (score 6):

You can pipe commands to the `bin/hbase shell` command.  From there you can use some scripting to grab the table names and pipe the disable/delete commands back to hbase.

i.e.

```
echo "list" | bin/hbase shell | ./filter_table_names.pl > table_names.txt
./turn_table_names_into_disable_delete_commands.pl table_names.txt | bin/hbase shell
```

Comment: Yes, but that depends on what output the hbase shell provides. I was hoping hbase would have something built-in.

Comment: You won't find that functionality from the shell and baja's method is about as close as you'll get. I don't think there are much in the way of plans to improve the current shell(which is pretty bad). I'm aware you want to avoid thrift/java but maybe if you can post your reasons for avoiding them another alternative could be suggested?

Answer (score 1):

There is a hack.
Open $HBASE_HOME/lib/ruby/shell/commands/list.rb file and add below line at the bottom of command method.

```
return list
```

After that, list command returns an array of names of all tables.
And then do just like this.

```
list.each {|t| disable t;drop t}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not deleting tables through the hbase shell but I deleting them from the command line by,

- deleting my hadoop distributed filesystem directory, then,

- creating a new clean hadoop distributed filesystem directory, then,

- formatting my hadoop distributed filesystem with 'hadoop namenode -format', then,

- start-all.sh and start-hbase.sh

Reference:

http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.1/api/overview-summary.html#overview_description

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something that will do this in a 'one-liner' via a shell script you can use this method:

```
$ echo 'list.each {|t| disable t; drop t}; quit;' | hbase shell
```

**NOTE:** The above was run from Bash shell prompt. It echoes the commands into `hbase shell` and does a loop through all the tables that are returned from the `list` command, and then disables & drops each table as it iterates through the array that `list` returned. Once it's done, it quits.