# How to delete all data from solr and hbase

Tags: solr, hbase

How do I delete all data from `solr` by command?  We are using `solr` with `lily` and `hbase`.

How can I delete data from both hbase and solr?

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_10_0/tutorial.html#Deleting+Data

Answer (score 228, accepted):

If you want to clean up Solr index -

you can fire http url -

```
http://host:port/solr/[core name]/update?stream.body=<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>&commit=true
```

(replace `[core name]` with the name of the core you want to delete from). Or use this if posting data xml data:

```
<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>
```

Be sure you use `commit=true` to commit the changes

Don't have much idea with clearing hbase data though.

Comment: core is needed if you are using multicore setup.

Comment: This answer discusses how to delete all the tables in hbase:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990952/a-script-that-deletes-all-tables-in-hbase.

If you want to just delete the data in the table, you can truncate them rather than drop them.

Comment: does it only delete the index? or will it delete the real data also?

Comment: Be sure to replace `core` with the name of your Solr core, otherwise you will receive a 404.

Comment: You might want to add `&commit=true` to the query so it becomes `http://host:port/solr/core/update?stream.body=<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>&commit=true` Without it I was wondering why all the documents were not removed.

Comment: defacto source for this everytime, gracias

Comment: It doesn't work. I get: HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /solr/update. Reason:
    Not Found  from solr...

Comment: I don't see I answer related to Solr GUI. How do I remove all the data from a core over the Solr GUI?

Answer (score 93):

I've used this request to delete all my records but sometimes it's necessary to commit this.

For that, add `&commit=true` to your request :

```
http://host:port/solr/core/update?stream.body=<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>&commit=true
```

Answer (score 27):

Post json data (e.g. with curl)

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    'http://<host>:<port>/solr/<core>/update?commit=true' \
    -d '{ "delete": {"query":"*:*"} }'
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use the following commands to delete.
Use the "match all docs" query in a delete by query command:

```
'<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>
```

You must also commit after running the delete so, to empty the index, run the following two commands:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update --data '<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>' -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update --data '<commit/>' -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'
```

Another strategy would be to add two bookmarks in your browser:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/update?stream.body=<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>
http://localhost:8983/solr/update?stream.body=<commit/>
```

Source docs from SOLR: 
https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FAQ#How_can_I_delete_all_documents_from_my_index.3F

Answer (score 10):

If you want to delete all of the data in Solr via SolrJ do something like this.

```
public static void deleteAllSolrData() {
    HttpSolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8080/solr/core/");
    try {
      solr.deleteByQuery("*:*");
    } catch (SolrServerException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Failed to delete data in Solr. "
          + e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Failed to delete data in Solr. "
          + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

If you want to delete all of the data in HBase do something like this.

```
public static void deleteHBaseTable(String tableName, Configuration conf) {
    HBaseAdmin admin = null;    
    try {
        admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf);
        admin.disableTable(tableName);
        admin.deleteTable(tableName);
    } catch (MasterNotRunningException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to delete the table " + tableName
        + ". The actual exception is: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (ZooKeeperConnectionException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to delete the table " + tableName
        + ". The actual exception is: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to delete the table " + tableName
        + ". The actual exception is: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        close(admin);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the "match all docs" query in a delete by query command: *:*

You must also commit after running the delete so, to empty the index, run the following two commands:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update --data '<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>' -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'

curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update --data '<commit/>' -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'
```

Comment: Worked well with `<core>` defined in the url. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I came here looking to delete all documents from solr instance through .Net framework using SolrNet. Here is how I was able to do it:

```
Startup.Init<MyEntity>("http://localhost:8081/solr");
ISolrOperations<MyEntity> solr =
    ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<MyEntity>>();
SolrQuery sq = new SolrQuery("*:*");
solr.Delete(sq);
solr.Commit();
```

This has cleared all the documents. *(I am not sure if this could be recovered, I am in learning and testing phase of Solr, so please consider backup before using this code)*

Comment: This is very useful . Thank you !

Answer (score 4):

From the command line use:

```
 bin/post -c core_name -type text/xml -out yes -d $'<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>'
```

Answer (score 3):

fire this in the browser

`http://localhost:8983/solr/update?stream.body=<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>&commit=true`
 this commmand will delete all the documents in index in solr

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it could really help.

Comment: is the above answer ok now ..?

Comment: It's certainly more understood :).

Answer (score 3):

I've used this query to delete all my records.

```
http://host/solr/core-name/update?stream.body=%3Cdelete%3E%3Cquery%3E*:*%3C/query%3E%3C/delete%3E&commit=true
```

Answer (score 3):

To delete all documents of a Solr collection, you can use this request:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"delete":{"query":"*:*" }}' http://localhost:8983/solr/my_collection/update?commit=true
```

It uses the JSON body.

Comment: As pointed out by others, it's probably better to use `/update?commit=true`. The JSON request body itself works great :)

Answer (score 2):

The curl examples above all failed for me when I ran them from a cygwin terminal. There were errors like this when i ran the script example.

```
curl http://192.168.2.20:7773/solr/CORE1/update --data '<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>' -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">1</int></lst>
</response>
<!-- 
     It looks like it deleted stuff, but it did not go away
     maybe because the committing call failed like so 
-->
curl http://192.168.1.2:7773/solr/CORE1/update --data-binary '' -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">400</int><int name="QTime">2</int></lst><lst name="error"><str name="msg">Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]</str><int name="code">400</int></lst>
</response>
```

I needed to use the delete in a loop on core names to wipe them all out in a project.

This query below worked for me in the Cygwin terminal script.

```
curl http://192.168.1.2:7773/hpi/CORE1/update?stream.body=<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>&commit=true
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">1</int></lst>
</response>
```

This one line made the data go away and the change persisted.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the below steps. It works well.

- Please make sure the SOLR server it running
- Just click the link [Delete all SOLR data](http://localhost:8080/solr/collection1/update?stream.body=%3Cdelete%3E%3Cquery%3E*:*%3C/query%3E%3C/delete%3E&commit=true) which will hit and delete all your SOLR indexed datas then you will get the following details on the screen as output.

  ```xml
  <response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
      <int name="status">0</int>
      <int name="QTime">494</int>
    </lst>
  </response>
  ```
- if you are not getting the above output then please make sure the following.

  - I used the default `host` (localhost) and `port` (8080) on the above link. please alter the host and port if it is different in your end.
  - The default core name should be `collection` / `collection1`. I used `collection1` in the above link. please change it too if your core name is different.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to clean out all data, it might be faster to recreate collection, e.g.

```
solrctl --zk localhost:2181/solr collection --delete <collectionName>
solrctl --zk localhost:2181/solr collection --create <collectionName> -s 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a JavaScript bookmark which adds the delete link in Solr Admin UI

```js
javascript: (function() {
    var str, $a, new_href, href, upd_str = 'update?stream.body=<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>&commit=true';
    $a = $('#result a#url');
    href = $a.attr('href');
    str = href.match('.+solr\/.+\/(.*)')[1];
    new_href = href.replace(str, upd_str);
    $('#result').prepend('<a id="url_upd" class="address-bar" href="' + new_href + '"><strong>DELETE ALL</strong>   ' + new_href + '</a>');
})();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Cloudera 5.x, Here in this documentation is mentioned that Lily maintains the Real time updations and deletions also.

[Configuring the Lily HBase NRT Indexer Service for Use with Cloudera Search](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/search_config_hbase_indexer_for_search.html)

> As HBase applies inserts, updates, and deletes to HBase table cells,
>   the indexer keeps Solr consistent with the HBase table contents, using
>   standard HBase replication.

Not sure if`truncate 'hTable'` is also supported in the same.

Else you create a Trigger or Service to clear up your data from both Solr and HBase on a particular Event or anything.

Answer (score 0):

When clearing out a Solr index, you should also do a commit and optimize after running the delete-all query.  Full steps required (curl is all you need): http://www.alphadevx.com/a/365-Clearing-a-Solr-search-index

Answer (score 0):

Solr I am not sure but you can delete all the data from hbase using truncate command like below:

```
truncate 'table_name'
```

It will delete all row-keys from hbase table.