# Not able to delete solr documents (using a query) either using post tool or URL

Tags: java, solr, bulkupdate, solr6

I am not able to delete solr documents (using a query) either using post tool or URL.

Please note, my solr is configured with basic authentication.
Solr Version : **`6.6`**

I tried two ways,

1. Using post tool

`./post -u username:pass -c core_name delete_by_timestamp.xml` here delete_by_timestamp.xml looks like,

```
<delete>
   <query>timestamp:[* TO 2017-04-03T10:30:30Z]</query>
</delete>
```

This gives me `401 Unauthorized` response

2. Using the URL,

`http://username:pass@{ip_address}:8983/solr/core_name/update?stream.body=<delete><query>timestamp:[* TO 2017-04-03T10:30:30Z]</query></delete>&commit=true`

This gives me `NullPointerException`,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at 
org.apache.solr.query.SolrRangeQuery.createDocSet(SolrRangeQuery.java:156) at 
org.apache.solr.query.SolrRangeQuery.access$200(SolrRangeQuery.java:57) at 
org.apache.solr.query.SolrRangeQuery$ConstWeight.getSegState(SolrRangeQuery.java:412)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Use one of the queries below in the Document tab of Solr Admin UI:

XML:

```
<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>
```

JSON:

```
{'delete': {'query': '*:*'}}
```

Make sure to select the Document Type drop down to Solr Command (raw XML or JSON).

Comment: it's says success but actually documents are not deleting. Thanks

Comment: You'll have to commit after making any changes to the index.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question. Let's try this.

I tried the below steps. It works well.

- Please make sure the SOLR server it running
- Just click the link [Delete all SOLR data](http://localhost:8080/solr/collection1/update?stream.body=%3Cdelete%3E%3Cquery%3E*:*%3C/query%3E%3C/delete%3E&commit=true) which will hit and delete all your SOLR indexed datas then you will get the following details on the screen as output.

  ```xml
  <response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
      <int name="status">0</int>
      <int name="QTime">494</int>
    </lst>
  </response>
  ```
- if you are not getting the above output then please make sure the following.

  - I used the default `host` (localhost) and `port` (8080) on the above link. please alter the host and port if it is different in your end.
  - The default core name should be `collection` / `collection1`. I used `collection1` in the above link. please change it too if your core name is different.

[My Answer Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722508/how-to-delete-all-data-from-solr-and-hbase/58553348#58553348)

Comment: Hi Ganesa, thanks for your time. I already checked your answer even before posting this. Do you see the NPE error? Can you help why it could be?