# How to delete all the data and metadata in HBase WITHOUT uninstalling and reinstalling?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, recovery, repair

Running HBase in pseudo-distributed mode on my dev box.  Cloudera CDH4.  CentOS.

Somehow, my HBase installation has gotten totally corrupted.  I ran this command :

./bin/hbase hbck -repairHoles

and the readout ended with this :

```
Summary:
  -ROOT- is okay.
    Number of regions: 1
    Deployed on:  localhost.localdomain,60020,1340917622717
  .META. is okay.
    Number of regions: 1
    Deployed on:  localhost.localdomain,60020,1340917622717
5 inconsistencies detected.
```

Looking at the documentation here :

http://hbase.apache.org/book/apbs03.html

it says this :
If inconsistencies still remain after these steps, you most likely have table integrity problems related to orphaned or overlapping regions.

Basically, I have no interest in digging in and trying to fix this.  I want to completely nuke my HBase installation and start over fresh and clean.  HOWEVER, I do not want to do an uninstall/reinstall, because we use Cloudera, and I don't want to mess with their whole weird configuration and setup.

Is there a way to delete all the data and metadata in HBase WITHOUT uninstalling and reinstalling?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990952/a-script-that-deletes-all-tables-in-hbase

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not recommend this unless you are at the point of no return.

I do not know if this is the correct way to nuke the hbase data, but when I run into such inconsistencies I usually delete all the contents the directory which is holding hbase data.
So the place would be look for the following property in hbase-site.xml 
`hbase.rootdir`

I have not used this approach once the system got stable on my local dev machine. Usually if I shut down the cluster properly before shutting down the system, then I do not run into such problems.

Answer (score 0):

the answer above isn't the whole story, I found this with my hbase today. 
if you are running with zookeepers, you also need to delete those data kept by the zookeeper,
as I've posted in this question 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51857841/8428146