# About hbase, zookeeper.MetaTableLocator: Failed verification of hbase:meta, .NotServingRegionException

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I use hadoop2.7.3,Hbase 1.2.3, zookeeper 3.4.9.

Each time I stop the Hbase and restart it,it will throw the exception:

```
  [hadoop01:16000.activeMasterManager] zookeeper.MetaTableLocator: Failed        verification of hbase:meta,,1 at address=hadoop05,16020,1478663588885, exception=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.NotServingRegionException: Region hbase:meta,,1 is not online on hadoop05,16020,1478664215143
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.getRegionByEncodedName(HRegionServer.java:2922)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.getRegion(RSRpcServices.java:1059)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.getRegionInfo(RSRpcServices.java:1339)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.AdminProtos$AdminService$2.callBlockingMethod(AdminProtos.java:22233)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2180)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:112)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:133)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:108)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have search the exception,but the reasons(i.e,hdfs saftemode or about date of the servers) are all not satisfied my situation.and the zookeeper's log:

```
2016-11-09 03:34:49,900 [myid:2] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:2    cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@649] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x358483686110002 type:create cxid:0x1 zxid:0x100000040 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase/replication Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /hbase/replication
2016-11-09 03:34:50,810 [myid:2] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:2 cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@649] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x15848364a850001 type:create cxid:0x16 zxid:0x100000048 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase/replication/peers Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /hbase/replication/peers
2016-11-09 03:34:55,378 [myid:2] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:2 cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@649] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x15848364a850000 type:delete cxid:0x5b zxid:0x100000049 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase/meta-region-server Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /hbase/meta-region-server
2016-11-09 03:34:56,677 [myid:2] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:2 cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@649] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x15848364a850001 type:setData cxid:0x2d zxid:0x10000004e txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase/meta-region-server Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /hbase/meta-region-server
2016-11-09 03:34:57,556 [myid:2] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:2 cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@649] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x15848364a850000 type:create cxid:0x30c zxid:0x100000052 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase/table-lock/hbase:namespace Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /hbase/table-lock/hbase:namespace
2016-11-09 03:35:00,443 [myid:2] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:2 cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@649] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x15848364a850000 type:create cxid:0x330 zxid:0x100000062 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase/namespace/default Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /hbase/namespace/default
2016-11-09 03:35:00,510 [myid:2] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:2 cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@649] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x15848364a850000 type:create cxid:0x333 zxid:0x100000064 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase/namespace/hbase Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /hbase/namespace/hbase
```

The hbase-sie.xml

[image]

The zoo.cfg

[image]

Comment: is there any error log on /var/log/zookeeper/

Comment: The zookeeper's leader log just like that I post here, any help? Thanks @NirmalRam

Comment: can you share your hbase-site.xml

Comment: sure,I will post that

Comment: check zookeeper is running properly -> $ZOOKEEPER_HOME/bin/zkServer.sh status

Comment: ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /home/zookeeper-3/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Mode: leader

Comment: ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /home/zookeeper-3/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Mode: follower

Comment: the leader and follower is nomal. any help?

Comment: try replacing value of    zookeeper.znode.parent to /hbase-unsecure and try again

Comment: Is there any difference?  any chance the zookeeper's version is too high?

Comment: Hi, This exception does not show as ERROR,but show as INFO.

Comment: so, when you type jps, Hmaster and Hregionserver running?

Comment: yes. This is not a problem?

Comment: Did you try disable this table and enable it again?

Answer (score 2):

I also met this problem.
first you can try to repair the data

> bin/hbase clean
>
> Usage: hbase clean (--cleanZk|--cleanHdfs|--cleanAll)
>   Options:
>
> ```
> --cleanZk   cleans hbase related data from zookeeper.
> --cleanHdfs cleans hbase related data from hdfs.
> --cleanAll  cleans hbase related data from both zookeeper and hdfs.
> ```

also,you may just delete your whole zookeepers' data,
which may be configured by hbase-site.xml or zoo.cfg,or even the default dirs, you can check your configuration files for that