# Shell script for executing hbase commands - Deleting all hbase tables

Tags: shell, hbase

I want to delete all tables in HBase. I am using HBase shell commands for doing this operation:

```
$ hbase shell
 > disable_all .*
 > drop_all .*
```

How can i write a shell script for doing this operations ?

Note: While executing above commands, it asks for the user confirmation i.e y/n before disabling and dropping all tables.

Comment: is there any way i can delete this tables forcefully ? i.e. without asking for a confirmation ?

Comment: Looks like it's answered before :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990952/a-script-that-deletes-all-tables-in-hbase

Comment: Yes, but the script is in Python. I wanted to write a shell script.

Comment: Cloudera has a section about this: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-7-x/topics/cdh_ig_hbase_shell.html#section_tfd_v5v_ls

Answer (score 16):

I use the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -e "disable_all '.*'\ny" | hbase shell -n
echo -e "drop_all '.*'\ny" | hbase shell -n
```

The `-e` flag to echo causes it to process escape sequences so you can build the confirmation into it.   The `-n` tells hbase shell this is a non-interactive session.

Comment: `-n` flag is very helpful, since run commands from file and redirect the output to another file will get hbase shell blocked without this flag

Answer (score 7):

Shell Script : deleteHbaseTables.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "disable_all .* " | hbase shell 
echo "drop_all .* " | hbase shell
```

Comment: this doesn't work because it asks for a confirmation before disabling and dropping the tables.

Comment: Excellent.  I have seen this paradigm for interacting with the mail utility: passing commands via pipe.  I had tried hbase shell "list" but did not work.

Answer (score 4):

This script will fetch all the tables from HBase and perform disable and drop operation on 1 table at a time.

```
#Creating a temp file to store the output of "list" command.
echo "list" | hbase shell > tableListSummary.txt

#fetch only the list of tables and store it in an another temp file.
tail -1 tableListSummary.txt > tableList.txt

#Separate tables by commas and iterate to perform disable and drop commands.
cat tableList.txt | sed -n 1'p' | tr ',' '\n' | while read word; do
    com=$(echo "$word" | sed 's/[][]//g')
    table="${com#\"}"
    table="${table%\"}"
    echo $table
    echo "disable '$table'" | hbase shell
    echo "drop '$table'" | hbase shell
done

#removing temporary files
rm tableListSummary.txt tableList.txt
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a hbase version with "--non-interactive / -n" option, example from [Cloudera](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-7-x/topics/cdh_ig_hbase_shell.html#section_tfd_v5v_ls):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'list' | hbase shell -n
status=$?
if [$status -ne 0]; then
  echo "The command may have failed."
fi
```

If you are using hbase 1.0.0 without "--non-interactive", you can load commands from a file. Example from [HBase documentation](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/src/main/asciidoc/_chapters/shell.adoc#4-read-hbase-shell-commands-from-a-command-file):

```
echo "create 'test', 'cf'" > ./sample_commands.txt
hbase shell ./sample_commands.txt
```

Comment: Hi Angelcervera, This "status" wont work because the status whatever you have mentioned actually checks the  successful unix command execution not the actual hbase execution. Any given time $? checks the unix command execution. Please correct if I am wrong

Comment: Hi @karthi I used it and I don't remember to have problems. In fact, that code is from Cloudera documentation. The link to the source is in the answer, just before the code fragment.

Answer (score 2):

1. input your hbase commands in a file :
   myfile.txt
2. run : 
   "hbase shell < myfile.txt"
3. observe the hbase output on screen.
4. alternatively , output all from the command into a file with this :
   "hbase shell < myfile.txt > IwantToseeTheOutputOfThis.log"